# Intercepting attributes in python

Tags: python, attributes

I wasn't able to figure out what to search for this, so if it's already out there, I apologize in advance, and would be happy to just take a search reference to somewhere else.

Some background: I'm working on some extra features for [a python Excel library](https://github.com/kz26/PyExcelerate) and one thing I'd like to be able to do is apply a style to a range of cells in a single call. Right now, our code permits us to do something like `ws[1][1].font.bold = True` to bold cell A1. We also have a range operator that permits us to do something like `ws.range("A1:B2").value = 1` to set all the values in that range to 1.

What I'd like to do now is add the ability to do `ws.range("A1:B2").font.bold = True`, but I can't figure out how. `range("A1:B2")` is an object that doesn't explicitly reference the cells (just the two corners to save on space), but does not explicitly have the `.font` or `.value` attribute, rather it's intercepted via a `@property` decorator to apply appropriately.

The thing is, if I add an `@property` decorator to create a `font` property, I can return a new font object, but I have no way of getting this font object after the `bold` attribute has been modified to apply it to all the cells in the range.

I was thinking I could `yield` the font, then add the apply logic after the `yield`, but that doesn't work as `yield` returns a generator. The only other idea I can think of is to create an explicit `.font` object, then in the `Range` class, override `.font.__setattr__` to listen for changes, but then I can't figure out how to get the original range from within `__setattr__` that needs to be applied without having to create a third intermediary class. Not only does that seem rather awkward, it also seems incredibly unpythonic.

Is something like this possible without having to result to rather esoteric methods? I hope my explanation was clear and again, if it's already out there, feel free to point me to an existing reference -- I just didn't know what to search for.

Comment: You're almost there with your last idea. Create a `.font` object that holds a reference to the original `Range`. Then override `__setattr__()` in the `.font` to update styles of all cells in the range.

Comment: In fact you could probably do this generically if you wanted, by having `Range` return the same "fake" property for any attribute name, and have it delegate all `__setattr__` calls to the original.

Comment: Ah, okay, that seems like it might work, but there's not a less esoteric way to do it? I feel like that would be incredibly confusing to maintain.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is an esoteric thing. You want a write to the `font`'s attributes to be applied to all cells in a range. So, you intercept writes to `font`'s attributes, and apply them to all cells in the correct range. It's really the most straightforward way to do it - you don't need to detect modifications on the `.font` or anything, you just write back things immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on my comment, you'd do something like:

```
class RangeFont(object):

    def __init__(self, range):
        self._range = range

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name.startswith('_'):
            super(RangeFont, self).__setattr__(name, value)
            return

        for cell in self._range: # assuming a range is iterable
            setattr(cell.font, name, value)


class Range(object):
    @property
    def font(self):
        return RangeFont(self)
```

A limitation of the above code is that it won't work for further levels of attributes, that is, you can't do `ws.Range(...).font.foo.bar = 123`. (That said you could extend this by having `RangeFont.__getattr__` return a similar wrapper object.)

Comment: okay, after giving up a couple times, I managed to implement this generically for deeper levels without having to make it too much more complicated: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=aAqmq554 :)

Comment: @kevmo314 Oh, derp, I didn't remember you need to work around the setattr override in `__init__`. Anyway, glad you got what you need.